# Convex closure (need for proof explanation)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I got stuck while reading a proof regarding convex sets (Corollary 2). I was supposed to use the first statement and Corollary 1 below, if necessary.

**First statement(theorem):**

Let $S$ be a convex set in $R^{n}$ with a nonempty interior. Let $x_{1} \in \operatorname{cl} S$ and $x_{2} \in$ int
S. Then $\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda) x_{2} \in$ int $S$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1)$.

**Corollary 1:**

Let $S$ be a convex set. Then int $S$ is convex.

**Corollary 2:**

Let $S$ be a convex set with a nonempty interior. Then cl $S$ is convex.

**-> Proof by the Author:**

Let $x_{1}, x_{2} \in \operatorname{cl} S .$ Pick $z \in$ int $S$ (by assumption, int $\left.S \neq \varnothing\right) .$ By the
theorem, $\lambda x_{2}+(1-\lambda) z \in$ int $S$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1) .$ Now fix $\mu \in(0,1) .$ By the
theorem, $\mu \mathbf{x}_{1}+(1-\mu)\left[\lambda \mathbf{x}_{2}+(1-\lambda) \mathbf{z}\right] \in$ int $S \subset S$ for each $\lambda \in(0,1) .$ If we take
the limit as $\lambda$ approaches $1,$ it follows that $\mu \mathrm{x}_{1}+(1-\mu) \mathrm{x}_{2} \in cl(S),$ and the proof is complete.

*From the book: Nonlinear Programming (Theory and Algorithms)*

**Where am i stuck?**

I just cannot understand the part where the author says:

> "If we take the limit as $\lambda$ approaches $1,$ it follows that
> $\mu \mathrm{x}_{1}+(1-\mu) \mathrm{x}_{2} \in cl(S)..."$

I can see that the limit equals $\mu \mathrm{x}_{1}+(1-\mu) \mathrm{x}_{2}$. However, two things are really bothering me:

1. I thought that $\lambda$ was a fixed number in $(0, 1)$ and because of that i should not be able to just "consider $\lambda$ as it approaches 1". Why can he do that?
2. I cannot see why $\mu \mathrm{x}_{1}+(1-\mu) \mathrm{x}_{2} \in cl(S)$. It has something to do with the set inclusions $int(S) \subset S \subset cl(S)$? Or does it have something to do with the fact that $S$ is convex? I also considered the possibility that the limit points are also in $S$ since $cl(S)$ is closed.

Can someone help me? I am really struggling.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: (#1) The statement is true for *every* choice of $\lambda$ in $(0,1)$. That means it's true for $\lambda = 0.9$, $\lambda = 0.99$, $\lambda = 0.999$, etc., and you can choose these $\lambda$ such that their limit is $1$. (#2) What is your definition of $\textrm{cl}(S)$?

Comment: Regarding the $\lambda$ thing, i finally understood it! Thank you.

Comment: Let $S$ be an arbitrary set in $R^{n}$. A point $x$ is said to be in the closure of $S$, denoted by $\operatorname{cl} S,$ if $S \cap N_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{x}) \neq \varnothing$ for every $\varepsilon>0 .$ If $S=\mathrm{cl} S, S$ is called closed. (Definition used by the authors of the book)

Comment: (Definition for closed sets): A set $S$ is closed if and only if for any convergent sequence of points $\left\{\mathbf{x}_{k}\right\}$ contained in $S$ with limit point $\overline{\mathbf{x}},$ we also
have that $\bar{x} \in S .$

Comment: Thanks; I added an answer below. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: It makes much more sense now! However, i am having problems applying the definition of closure. How can i write it properly?

Comment: Oh, i think i got it. Saying that $L \in cl(S)$ is equivalent to saying that $L$ is the limit of a sequence of points in the set, which is exactly the case. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :) It seems like you've got it now, but just to be clear, here are some further comments on your earlier thoughts: "Does it have something to do with the fact that $S$ is convex?" The convexity of $S$ is used in both lines that start with "by the theorem". Next: "I also considered the possibility that the limit points are also in $S$." Careful: the limit points are not necessarily in $S$, since it may not be closed; this is precisely the point of taking the closure.

Comment: Super duper great explanation, thank you very much! One last question: If the proof went like: "Fix $\lambda \in (0, 1)$...." Then i would not be able to take the limit towards 1, since $\lambda$ would be fixed. Is that correct?

Comment: Finally, it might help to draw an example: consider the open set $S = \{(x,y) : 0 < x,y < 1\}$, i.e., the interior of a unit square. The closure includes the perimeter of the square. Now take $\mathbf{x_1} = (0,1)$ and $\mathbf{x_2} = (1,1)$. Following the proof, $z$ will be any point inside the square; the line segment $\mathcal{L}$ between $z$ and $\mathbf{x_2}$ is inside the square; and then we form line segments from $\mathbf{x_1}$ to points on $\mathcal{L}$ as those points approach $\mathbf{x_2}$. In the limit, we end up with the line segment along the top of the square.

Comment: Glad to help! And correct, it would make no sense to fix $\lambda$. Compare this with $z$, which is fixed and where it really doesn't matter which point you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(#1) The statement is true for *every* choice of $\lambda \in (0,1)$. That means it's true for $\lambda=0.9, \lambda=0.99, \lambda=0.999$, etc., and you can choose these $\lambda$ such that their limit is $1$.

(#2) You have a sequence of points $\mu \mathbf{x}_{1}+(1-\mu)\left[\lambda \mathbf{x}_{2}+(1-\lambda) \mathbf{z}\right] \in S$. Taking the limit as $\lambda \to 1$, you can see the points approach $\mu \mathbf{x}_{1}+(1-\mu)\mathbf{x_2}$. In other words, this is a convergent sequence of points contained in $S$; now apply your definition of closure.